# Passing array by reference in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have created a `string (array of characters)` that I am trying to pass to a function within my main to be modified within the subfunction. In my main, I declare/initialize the array as such:

```
char line[300];
```

My header to my subfunction is

```
 int encrypt_function(char *line[]){
    }
```

in which I intend to change the letters of the original string from main so that when I exit my encrypt function and try to print my string in my main function, the `line` string is different from when I passed it to `encrypt_function`.

My call to encrypt_function is:

```
encrypt_function(*line);
```

I am getting a seg fault-- what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Segmentation fault is due to memory access violation. 
Your function should be in the format

```
int encrypt_function(char *line);
```

and you have to call function  like

```
encrypt_function(&line[0]);
```

or

```
encrypt_function(line);
```

Comment: why the unnecessary reference/index? just call it like `encrypt_function(line);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `int encrypt_function(char *line[]){ }` is equal to `int encrypt_function(char **line){ }`. Just use `int encrypt_function(char *line){ }` or `int encrypt_function(char line[]){ }` for your problem.

The segmentation fault is raised by memory protection.

Answer (score 0):

When calling to encrypt_function, you need to pass &line and not *line.

BUT:

If you only want to change the contnet of the buffer, you don't need an additional pointer.

```
int encrypt_function(char *line);
```

preferably. to manipulate it safely, you should also pass the size:

```
int encrypt_function(char *line, int size);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to use a function using pass by reference, we need to use the pointer as a reference. Here in line[300], the variable line is a pointer to an array of 300 elements. Hence you can directly pass line to the function instead of *line .  encrypt_function(line). This is so because line itself is a pointer.

And in the declaration declare the function as encrypt_function(char *line) or encrypt_function(char line[]).